# How to disable cursor jumps to the beginning of the css file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

If I use Ctrl+S to save the .css file, cursor always jumps at the beginning of the file. Is it a feature or a bug? How do I disable it? It's so annoying.

Comment: Thx, so it must be some plugin or ... I couldn't remember if I had this problem before, because I was using external css editor ;-)

Comment: See comment below, CodeMaid v0.3.3 works around the Visual Studio bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Ctrl + K + D bug. CodeMaid uses this shortcut automatically.

Comment: It is a bug in Visual Studio's format document, which like you said CodeMaid utilizes.  As of v0.3.3 CodeMaid works around the Visual Studio bug and keeps the cursor from moving on cleanup.

Comment: I haven't realized that it's your baby :-) Great job Steve. Thx for CodeMaid, it's one of the most used pieces of software on my dev machine ;-)